# Coding Bayesian Neural Network in TensorFlow Probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to use TensorFlow Probability to implement Bayesian Deep Learning for a bioinformatics regression task. The closest analogy in traditional data science would be image scoring where the model attempts to predict  label (float value) as close to the true label as possible.

I have previously trained a model on my dataset with normal dense layers in TensorFlow and it does converge and perform decently well on an independent test set. The bayesian network, however, does not seem to converge at all giving a loss of around 10,000 when the dense network eventually converges to a loss of less than 1. I think the error may lie in my implementation of the bayesian neural network. Any help would be much appreciated.

Below are code snippets from the bayesian neural network and the dense network I am trying to replace.

**Bayesian Neural Network**

```
kernel_divergence_fn=lambda q, p, _: tfp.distributions.kl_divergence(q, p)
bias_divergence_fn=lambda q, p, _: tfp.distributions.kl_divergence(q, p)

    interpretation1 = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(1000,bias_posterior_fn=tfp.layers.util.default_mean_field_normal_fn(),
                           bias_prior_fn=tfp.layers.default_multivariate_normal_fn,
                           kernel_divergence_fn=kernel_divergence_fn,
                           bias_divergence_fn=bias_divergence_fn,activation="relu")(merged)
    interpretation2 = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(500,bias_posterior_fn=tfp.layers.util.default_mean_field_normal_fn(),
                           bias_prior_fn=tfp.layers.default_multivariate_normal_fn,
                           kernel_divergence_fn=kernel_divergence_fn,
                           bias_divergence_fn=bias_divergence_fn,activation="relu")(interpretation1)
    interpretation3 = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(200,bias_posterior_fn=tfp.layers.util.default_mean_field_normal_fn(),
                           bias_prior_fn=tfp.layers.default_multivariate_normal_fn,
                           kernel_divergence_fn=kernel_divergence_fn,
                           bias_divergence_fn=bias_divergence_fn,activation="relu")(interpretation2)
    outputs = Dense(1)(interpretation3)
```

**Dense Neural Network**

```
dense1 = Dense(1000, activation="relu")(merged)
dense_drop1 = Dropout(0.35)(dense1)
dense2 = Dense(500, activation="relu")(dense_drop1)
dense_drop2 = Dropout(0.35)(dense2)
dense3 = Dense(200, activation="relu")(dense_drop2)
dense_drop3 = Dropout(0.35)(dense3)
```

Comment: Your post isn't clear on what the problem is. Is your model not fitting at all? Or is the performance not as good as the non-Bayesian model? 
A Bayesian model with not always lead to performance improvements over the same non-Bayesian model, and will often have different training dynamics (and different hyperparameters). If you can give more information on what the problem is we can try give more useful input.

Comment: @bigmac thank you for responding. Sorry I haven't been on StackExchange much recently. I have edited the question with more depth and the code of the dense network I am trying to replace.

Answer (score 1):

Can you include the lines where you compile and fit the data?

High value of loss corresponds to the contribution of Kl-divergence loss. Because you have fixed priors for all the layers, they often tend to get your approximate posteriors near to them and you observe a bad mean fit. One way to minimise the effect of prior is to use type II maximum likelihood estimation (also called Empirical Bayes) where one also updates the prior parameters in the learning stage. See this ([blog](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/03/regression-with-probabilistic-layers-in.html))for the reference.